# Let $f,g \in End(V)$ be simultaneously diagonalizable; then $f\circ g=g\circ f$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was studying and found a demonstration unfinished so i tried to finish it myself as it follows: If $f, g$ are simultaneously diagonalizable then exist $\mathscr{B}=\left( v_1,\dots,v_n \right)$ base of eigenvectors for both $f$ and $g$. Assuming $f(v_i)=\lambda_iv_i$ and $g(v_i)=\mu_iv_i$ then $$M_\mathscr{B}\left( f \right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
0& 0 &\dots & 0 & \lambda_n\\
\end{pmatrix}
,\; M_\mathscr{B}\left( g \right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0 \\
0 & \mu_2 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
0& 0 &\dots & 0 & \mu_n\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
now
$$
M_\mathscr{B}\left( f \circ g \right)= M_\mathscr{B}\left( f \right) \cdot M_\mathscr{B}\left( g \right) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \mu_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0 \\
0 & \lambda_2\mu_2 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
0& 0 &\dots & 0 & \lambda_n\mu_n\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
M_\mathscr{B}\left( g \circ f \right)= M_\mathscr{B}\left( g \right) \cdot M_\mathscr{B}\left( f \right) =
\begin{pmatrix}
 \mu_1 \lambda_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0 \\
0 & \mu_2\lambda_2 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
0& 0 &\dots & 0 & \mu_n\lambda_n\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
now clearly those two are actually the same matrix; therefore the thesis. It seems reasonable to me, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct